# how to toggle oem unlock from fastboot?

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, oneplus-two

i have flashed a new rom , nano gapps , a new firmware(which i think may be corrupt and have created problems),so now i see the oneplus logo for almost 500ms and then black screen appears though i can boot into fastboot mode but not into TWRP.
Main problem is I don`t have enabled oem unlock from developer option as i have just flashed a new ROM.So,i just need a method to toggle oem unlock further all things can be done by me.

company OnePlus
model OnePlus 2

Comment: Why don't you just flash a stock firmware and retry the installation of the custome ROM?

Comment: can you link me to a tutorial doing so,I couldn`t find  one.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I hope you did fix your problems long ago. If not, try this : https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3146568/post61613924

Answer (score 1):

Just try these fastboot commands:-

```
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot oem unlock-go
//To Toggle
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot oem lock-go
```